# What is different between R2 and mean of R2 in multiclassification probelm? Which one is correct?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, naive-bayes-classifier

I have a question. I have a big dataset (unfortunately confidential).

### What I did?

I have trained my model with Naive-Bayes.

```
BRNBReg=BernoulliNB(alpha=0.01, binarize=0.0, fit_prior=True, class_prior=None)
BRNBReg.fit(x_train,y_train)

#CrossValidation
cv_BRNBReg_score=cross_val_score(BRNBReg,x_train,y_train,cv=9)
cv_BRNBReg_pred=cross_val_predict(BRNBReg,x_train,y_train,cv=9)

print("R2-Socre-Mean: ",cv_BRNBReg_score.mean())
print("Score: ",r2_score(y_train,cv_BRNBReg_pred))

## Prediction 
BRNBReg_pred=BRNBReg.predict(x_test)
print("Score: ",r2_score(y_test,BRNBReg_pred))
```

My Score with CV is:

```
R2-Socre-Mean:  0.908198797087686
Score:  0.8673184920974637
```

### My problem:

My Score with `test-data` is:

```
Score:  0.6244917483855538
```

the difference is huge! But I don't know why?

- Is my model overfit\underfit?
- Shall i tune my hyperparams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are in a **classification** problem as you said, R2 score is not good, it should be used for regression problem. For classification problem you have to use something like accuracy, precision, recall and F1 score.

### First question

Anyway, I will answer your first question about R2score:

**R2 mean:** you are calculating the R2 for each split you have in your CV(train the model with training data, and evaluating it in test data). And then, you calculate the mean of each value of the split. In your case, you will have 9 values of R2score since you have 9 CV. And the result is the meaning of these values.

**r2_score:** you are evaluating the `y_true` and `y_pred`. You already have the `y_true`. To obtain the y_pred you used cross_val_predict. What you do, is calculate the predicted value using only the CV where you have the y_true in you test split.

I would recommend you use R2 mean, it's more robust score in my opinion

I recommend read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613443/difference-between-cross-val-score-and-cross-val-predict#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=cross_val_score%20returns%20score%20of%20test,values%20for%20the%20test%20fold.&text=Whereas%2C%20cross_val_predict()%20returns%2C%20for,was%20in%20the%20test%20set.) to understand it in more detail.

### Second questions

First of all, take care of what I mention: r2 is not a good score for classification problem. But let's suppose that you use another score and you have similar score outputs.

- Is my model overfit\underfit?

Yes, it is. Basically, if your training accuracy is much bigger than your test data, you are overfitting. Your scores must be quite similar. What you have now, is a model that is "memorizing" and not learning. Be careful.

- Shall I tune my hyperparams?

Yes, you have to try tunning your hyperparameters in order to achieve similar score between training data and test data. You should check how the model works changing hyperparameters and decided which helps you to avoid overfitting. You can do it manually or using `GridSearchCV` for example.

Comment: I have another question. Shall I use one time after CV-Step and one time after prediction with test values and compare these together?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) !